# Why the derivative of inverse secant has an absolute value?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

$y=\operatorname{arcsec}x$ can be defined in two ways. The first restricts the domain of $\sec y$ to $[0,\pi], y\neq\frac{\pi}{2}$. So the range of $y$ goes between $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})\cup(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ and the slope of the function is always positive. The derivative is

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

And when the domain of $\sec y$ function is defined as $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})\cup[\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2})$ the $\operatorname{arcsec}x$ has a negative slope for $x\leq-1$. That's why the derivative is

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

(It's just different in the absolute value). But what's the proof?

In my attempt to prove it, I'm using the theorem for derivate an inverse function, which is

$$\frac{d}{dx}[f^{-1}(x)]=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$

So, we have

$$\frac{d}{dx}[\operatorname{arcsec}(x)]=\frac{1}{\sec (\operatorname{arcsec}(x))\cdot\tan (\operatorname{arcsec}(x))}$$

At this point, I think is safe to say that $\sec (\operatorname{arcsec}(x))=x$ because this identity works for $|x|\geq1$, and that's the domain of $y$.

For the $\tan$, I'm using the right triangle diagram

[image: Right Triangle Diagram]

Where the hypotenuse is $x$, the adjacent side is 1 (so $\sec y=x$) and the opposite side is $\sqrt{x^2-1}$. The $\tan y$ results in $\sqrt{x^2-1}/1=\sqrt{x^2-1}$. Substituting we get

$$\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

But I don't understand where does the absolute value come from.

Reading other questions and watching some videos, I realize that the absolute value comes from the identity $\tan^2x+1=\sec^2x$, but as you can see, this prove doesn't use that identity.

Comment: I'm confused. Why should they be different? In both $dy/dx$ equalities, $x \ge 0$, so $|x|=x$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer, Not in the first case. $x\lt 0$ when $x\in (\pi/2,\pi)$

Comment: ... if $x \in (\pi / 2, \pi)$ it is immediately greater than zero. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer,either I am confused or this post needs an edit. While defining arc sec x, OP has considered $x\ne \pi/2$ which should have been $y\ne \pi/2$. And if $y\in (\pi/2,\pi)$ then indeed $x\lt 0$

Comment: Notice that in your right triangle diagram, the hypotenuse cannot be negative. So the hypotenuse should be labeled $|x|$ and the adjacent side should be labeled $\dfrac{x}{|x|}$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I meant, the domain of $\sec y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right triangle with hypotenuse $x$ and legs $1$ and $\sqrt{x^2-1}$
is a useful mnemonic device, but strictly speaking it is only valid
for $0 < y < \frac\pi2,$ because by definition the non-right angles in a right triangle are positive and acute.

When $\frac\pi2 < y \leq \pi,$ it turns out that actually $\tan y < 0.$
The correct formula in that case is $\tan y = -\sqrt{x^2-1},$ which you can find from the facts that $\tan y < 0$ and
$$ \tan^2 y = \sec^2 y - 1. $$

So if you define the arc secant function on $(-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty)$
so that its range is
$\left[0,\frac\pi2\right) \cup \left(\frac\pi2,\pi\right]$
then
$$
\tan(\operatorname{arcsec}(x)) = 
\begin{cases} \sqrt{x^2-1} & x \geq 1, \\ -\sqrt{x^2-1} & x \leq 1.
\end{cases} 
$$
On the other hand, you are correct when you say that
$\sec (\operatorname{arcsec}(x) = x$ for all $x$ in the domain of the arc secant.
When you use these equations to make substitutions in the formula
$$
\frac{d}{dx}[\operatorname{arcsec}(x)]
= \frac{1}{\sec(\operatorname{arcsec}(x)) \tan(\operatorname{arcsec}(x))},
$$
you get
$$
\frac{d}{dx}[\operatorname{arcsec}(x)] = 
\begin{cases}
 \dfrac{1}{x \cdot  \sqrt{x^2-1}} & x \geq 1, \\
 \dfrac{1}{x \cdot  (-\sqrt{x^2-1})} & x \leq 1.
\end{cases} 
$$
Now observe that if $x \geq 1$ then $\lvert x\rvert = x$ and therefore
$$\lvert x\rvert \cdot  \sqrt{x^2-1} = x \cdot  \sqrt{x^2-1},$$
whereas if $x \leq -1$ then $\lvert x\rvert = -x$ and therefore
$$\lvert x\rvert \cdot  \sqrt{x^2-1} = -x \cdot  \sqrt{x^2-1} 
= x \cdot  (-\sqrt{x^2-1}).$$
So both cases (positive and negative $x$) are correctly represented by
$\lvert x\rvert   \sqrt{x^2-1}.$

If we define the arc secant instead so that its range is
$\left[0,\frac\pi2\right) \cup \left(\pi,\frac32\pi\right]$,
then $\tan y > 0$ on all parts of the range and your derivation is completely correct.